# element.sendKeys(password) method in Selenium sending too many keys

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing Selenium tests for an application my company's working on. It's Selenium 3, and I'm using the 32-bit Internet Explorer Driver(IEDriverServer.exe) because I was using the 64-bit version but it was very slow to do anything.

I'm trying to populate a password field (with id="password"), and I'm using the following line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("welcome123");
```

where `driver` is an `InternetExplorerDriver`. What's happening instead of inputting the 10 characters "welcome123", is this:

[The image of the populated password field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRdYS.png)

Please let me know what I can do to stop this from happening. I don't know what keys are being sent, but I am sure that in my code it says just "welcome123" and not something obvious like "welcome123_________".

Thanks!

Comment: Try to do `click`, `clear` and after that `sendKeys`. `driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();`, 
`driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();`

Comment: I guess it was already populated because of the "saved password data" from IE?

Comment: Rather than editing your question, if you were able to figure out what was happening (saved data requiring clearing?), it's actually encouraged to write up your observations and solution as an answer to your own question, in case someone else runs into a similar problem.

Comment: are you able to login or not, because sometimes extra keys are inserted for encryption purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the lines

`driver.findElement(By.id("password")).click();` and

`driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();` and then following it up with the

`sendKeys("welcome123");`

method call, the field is populated correctly. The problem was because IE was auto populating the password field based on password saving settings, and it was just tacking "welcome123" on the to the end.